# Tasks for production prepared Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, build, gulp, ionic2, production-environment

I'm trying to figure out what's the *best* process to pass from the code to the final deployable apk/ipa.

So far I have a testsuite using Karma + Jasmine, which transpiles the TypeScript to JS and runs some unit tests. I start that process via gulp.

After that all I know is to `ionic build android --release` what generates (an unsigned yet) apk.
But I'm not sure of how ofuscated/minificated the generated apk is.

So, keeping in mind the code has to be as private as possible, is the minification and the ofuscation of the `ionic build` enough or should I do all those prebuild tasks manually via gulp? 
And in that case, whats are the right tasks I should run, do I have to transpile all the TypeScript files to JS manually? and in what order should I run the tasks?

E.g. `transpile -> tests -> minify -> uglify -> build apk` or `minify -> uglify -> transpile -> tests -> build apk`

I'm a bit lost with this, and the only thing I can figure out is that the tests should be ran first, because is case of test failure the process should be aborted.

Answer (score 3):

Try [ionic-app-scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration) >= 0.0.48 to config build.

Production:

```
ionic build android --prod
```

To check the minified file, open the apk file with `GNOME Archive Manager` (or similiar) and extract `/assets/www/build/js/app.bundle.js` file.

Comment: Due to new years holidays, I couldn't test you're proposal deeply, so can't accept or refuse the solution. I'm giving you the bounty just to avoid loosing it.

Answer (score 0):

## Preparing an Ionic Cordova app for release in production

#### 1. Building

In your terminal execute the following command according to your platform (android / ios):

`ionic build android --prod --release`

#### 2. Releasing

In order to be able to install a production application on a device and furthermore in order to be able to publish it in app stores, your .apk or .ipa
file needs to be *signed*. How you do that depends on the platform.

Here is the procedure in detail for [Android](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#signing-an-app) and for [iOS](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html#signing-an-app).

## Preparing an Ionic Progressive Web App (PWA) for release in production

#### 1. Building

In your `package.json` file, you should make sure to have something like the following:

```
"scripts": {
     // ...
     "build:www": "rm -rf www && ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
     // ...
},
```

Now in your terminal run:

`npm run build:www`

#### 2. Releasing

Your app is built in the folder `www` ready for you to serve in production using any webserver like [NginX](https://www.nginx.com/), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or a custom [Node + Express](http://mfranc.com/node-js/node-js-simple-web-server-with-express/) webserver.

---

*Valid as of Ionic v3.3*

[Learn more about `ionic-scripts`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/), what they do and which other scripts you could possibly find useful.