# Build Ionic Application From Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework

I'm building an iOS application using Xcode/Swift, and I have a few less-than-technical group members who don't really know how to build Xcode projects, but are interested in seeing/testing the progress of the application.  One group member pointed out that they could test the app using Ionic/Ionic View.  However, to my understanding, Ionic works by building an application in the specific Ionic framework, and then Ionic translates the project into an Xcode/Swift project (.xcodeproj) or an Android project.  Is there a way to do the reverse conversion––is there a way to convert my Xcode project so that it will work on Ionic, or specifically Ionic View?

Comment: what you are looking for is called "continuous delivery" or "continuous deployment".

Comment: perhaps this is what you need ?https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/

Answer (score 1):

Ionic is tool like cordova created to develop hybrid apps (from HTML+JS+CSS --> to Native iOS/Android/WinPhone/BlackBerry). The UI is running in native webView, and using some native functionalities by plugins but it is not created to make Ionic/Cordova app from native.

If you want to share your app to tests, use [Apple TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Answer (score 0):

**['Ionic View'](https://view.ionic.io/) is a very good advice and the one I would suggest in your case as well.**

You don't have to do anything in your code really to use it, just create an ionic account and in your terminal, change into your ionic project directory and then type:

```
$> ionic upload
```

You will be asked for the usernmame and password of the account you just created, the application will be uploaded and you will get a unique `app ID`. You can then share that ID with anyone who you want to test your app, as long as they have the `Ionic View` app installed on the their iOS or Android devices.

Also do make sure you have updated your global ionic and cordova packages to the latest version before you upload:

```
$> sudo npm uninstall -g ionic && sudo npm install ionic
```

Now, as 3squad mentioned, many of they [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) plugins are not supported so don't expect everything to work, but it's a good start to show most of your app and design running.

[Here's a list of currently supported plugins.](http://docs.ionic.io/tools/view/)

Please do keep in mind that the performance using Ionic View will be far worse than if you actually build, release and give your users and actual production `.apk` or `.ipa` file to install. This latter approach would also showcase the full, final performance and functionality resulting from your code, but it may be more cumbersome.

[Here's how to release a production version of your app.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383885/5015955)